# Is PIXEL based on LXDE or XFCE?

Tags: raspbian, gui, lxde, pixel

Is Raspberry Pi GUI PIXEL based on LXDE or XFCE? I found some commands starting by lx* and some xf*. Because there are more commands starting lx* I gues that LXDE is right answer but PIXEL shows more like XFCE.

On what environment is PIXEL based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIXEL is based on LXDE. The designers have remodeled the whole UI by creating new icons, windows and buttons to make it aesthetically pleasing.